# Photoshop: Where are the “Pressure for Opacity” and “Pressure for Size” in the custom shortcuts feature?

Tags: photoshop, tablet, keyboard-shortcuts

I am setting up Photoshop commands/tools/functions on a Wacom and would really like to have the "Pressure for Opacity" and "Pressure for Size" options as shortcuts—which would be very useful. There isn't a keyboard shortcut assigned to either of them by default and I tried searching in the custom shortcuts feature and looking it up online, but haven't found anything.

Where are "Pressure for Opacity" and "Pressure for Size" in the custom keyboard shortcuts feature in Photoshop?

You can check out the pictures below, to better get what I am referring to.

Regards.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has recently added both of these in the custom keyboard shortcuts function, in the 2015.5 release, all the way at the bottom of the 'Tools' list.

Wohooo!

[image: https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-8858495-975777/tog.png]